# mPDF generate file with the content from a PDF or DOC files

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf, doc

I am generating Certificates in PDF format from HTML, using the PHP library mPDF.

For some certificates there are some documents such as .doc or .pdf, linked to the Certificate that should be included in the same PDF file once is generated.

This means that the final PDF will be a merge of the Certificate PDF and the other files.

Does anyone know how could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to add a link (href) to other files or are you trying to convert and merge multiple files (pdf, doc) into a single pdf file?

Comment: Hi @DanielO, I am trying the second, to merge all the files in just one PDF. Is it possible to do it at the same time I am generating the certificate with mPDF or the only way is after?

Comment: Do you have a Windows webserver?

Comment: Yes, I use IIS. From the admin side of the website, I generate different Certificates and I need that the final PDF contains others files which are linked to the certificate.

Comment: I could implement a PHP library for that.